# How to make sure that hotkey only launches UserForm for active workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

In a template's `workbook_open` event, I have a hotkey `^m` registered to launch a UserForm `DataValidation`:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Application.OnKey "^m", "launchDataValidation"

End Sub

Sub launchDataValidation()

DataValidation.Show

End Sub
```

It's possible that there will be multiple workbooks open at the same time that are built from this template.  I want to make sure that when the user presses the hotkey, the UserForm that is launched is from the active workbook, so that any operations executed by that UserForm will only affect that workbook.

I tried rewriting `launchDataValidation` as:

```
Sub launchDataValidation()

On Error GoTo errHandler

ActiveWorkbook.DataValidation.Show
Exit Sub

errHandler:

End Sub
```

The intent is that the active workbook's `DataValidation` form opens, and if the active book doesn't have a `DataValidation` form, nothing happens.  But instead, the `ActiveWorkbook.DataValidation.Show` call goes to the error handler, suggesting that this is not the correct way to open that form in the active workbook.

I also tried:

```
Sub launchDataValidation()

Dim bkName As String
Dim runString As String

bkName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
runString = "'" & bkName & "'!DataValidation.Show"

On Error GoTo errHandler

Application.Run runString

Exit Sub

errHandler:

End Sub
```

This also threw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Application.OnKey "^m", "launchDataValidation_ActiveBook"

End Sub


Sub launchDataValidation()

DataValidation.Show

End Sub


Sub launchDataValidation_ActiveBook()

Dim bkName As String
Dim runString As String

bkName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
runString = "'" & bkName & "'!launchDataValidation"

On Error GoTo errHandler

Application.Run runString

Exit Sub

errHandler:

End Sub
```